# mysql lock tables causing certain inserts to fail randomly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I recently adding locking to a query to prevent a deadlock. This problem is solved, but now I am having a problem where inserts into one table are randomly failing with no cause. I

I have turned on the general query log to see exactly what is happening. Is there any other way to debug this to see exactly what is happening or have any ideas of the cause?

If I perform the following lock:

```
$this->db->query('LOCK TABLES '.$this->db->dbprefix('customers').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales').' WRITE, 
'.$this->db->dbprefix('store_accounts').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_payments').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items').' WRITE, 
'.$this->db->dbprefix('giftcards').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_items').' WRITE, 
'.$this->db->dbprefix('inventory').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_items_taxes').' WRITE,
'.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_item_kits').' WRITE, '.$this->db->dbprefix('sales_item_kits_taxes').' WRITE,'.$this->db->dbprefix('people').' READ,'.$this->db->dbprefix('items').' READ
,'.$this->db->dbprefix('employees_locations').' READ,'.$this->db->dbprefix('locations').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('items_tier_prices').' READ
, '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_items_tier_prices').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('items_taxes').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('item_kits').' READ
, '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_item_kits').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('item_kit_items').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('employees').' READ , '.$this->db->dbprefix('item_kits_tier_prices').' READ
, '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_item_kits_tier_prices').' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_items_taxes').' READ
, '.$this->db->dbprefix('location_item_kits_taxes'). ' READ, '.$this->db->dbprefix('item_kits_taxes'). ' READ');


    foreach($items as $line=>$item)
    {
        if (isset($item['item_id']))
        {
            $cur_item_info = $this->Item->get_info($item['item_id']);

            $sales_items_data = array
            (
                'sale_id'=>$sale_id,
                'item_id'=>$item['item_id'],
                'line'=>$item['line'],
                'description'=>$item['description'],
                'serialnumber'=>$item['serialnumber'],
                'quantity_purchased'=>$item['quantity'],
                'discount_percent'=>$item['discount'],
                'item_cost_price' => $cur_item_info->cost_price,
                'item_unit_price'=>$item['price']
            );

            $this->db->insert('sales_items',$sales_items_data);
        }
        ...
        ...
    }

$this->db->query('UNLOCK TABLES');
```

Table:

```
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| phppos_sales_items | CREATE TABLE `phppos_sales_items` (
  `sale_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `serialnumber` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `line` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `quantity_purchased` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `item_cost_price` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL,
  `item_unit_price` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL,
  `discount_percent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sale_id`,`item_id`,`line`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_items` (`item_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_sales_items_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_sales` (`sale_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

Then insert into a bunch of tables but randomly I am getting an error where data does NOT make it into sales_items, but correctly makes it into other tables using the item_id foreign key...is there a scenario that can causes inserts to fail randomly because of the locks? I am going to turn on the general query log to see what is happening but I cannot track it down. This never happened before until I added the locking.

Comment: Just to confirm a few things - you were using *transactions* before, but that caused a deadlock, after which you decided to control the insertion by locking all tables in question, after which foreign key gets inserted but table providing that key doesn't store the record?

Comment: @N.B. correct. It is random which item(s) don't get stored in the table. It doesn't happen all the time, but it happens 2 or 3 times a week. I just enabled the general query log to figure out why, but I would love any ideas on how to reproduce. The foreign key record doesn't get stored for sales_items table, but it does for another table with the same foreign key value.

Comment: I've never had such a problem, I don't even think it's possible. You can't get a value of a FK, insert into one table and fail to do it with another. Are you sure all your tables are InnoDB and not MyISAM? Have you checked the health of your hard drives? Bear in mind that locks aren't reliable at all, it's better to have a deadlock that you can detect and rollback after which you try the insert again opposed to a locking approach.

Comment: @N.B. what do you mean by locks aren't reliable? Can they cause errors such as this?

Comment: Locks are not a reliable mechanism to successfully write something to the disk - you can have a process that doesn't release the lock, which will eventually happen and you'll have to manually connect to MySQL daemon and release it. Deadlocks are fine, it's not a problem if you get them. You should have a function in your language of choice that deals with initiating the transaction and issuing inserts. If you end up with a deadlock, just re-initiate the whole mechanism of starting a transaction and inserting.

Comment: @nb are you sure that a lock will exclusively not allow writes if it is not released during the session? See http://mark.koli.ch/if-a-php-script-locks-a-mysql-table-then-dies-with-an-unexpected-error-is-the-table-left-in-a-locked

Comment: That's if a **php** script dies. PHP scripts have a cleanup mechanism that gets executed even in case of script dying, so those kind of locks can be released. What you're doing is controlling something that MySQL does (acquiring exclusive lock upon write), but you do it in a language instead letting the service (MySQL) itself take care of it. Locks will produce more problems that a deadlock during transaction. If you have a simple case of deadlock, and you do, what you have to do is just restart the whole transaction. You can keep using locks if you want to, but they're not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was related to mysql 5.6 default strict mode setting. Not related to lock